# Bash scripting, two files with the same name in another directories

Tags: bash, scripting

So, I have two files with the same name in two different directories, one is in /usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts/ and the other one in /usr/local/nagios/etc/services/.

I was trying to copy lines in the first file that contains contact* to the other file with the same name in another directory.

First file looks like this:

```
 define host {
    host_name                       10.80.12.62
    address                         10.80.12.79
    check_command                   check-host-alive!!!!!!!!
    max_check_attempts              4
    check_interval                  5
    retry_interval                  2
    check_period                    24x7
    contacts                        Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić
    contact_groups                  Testna
    register                        1
    }
```

And another like this:

```
 define service {      
    host_name                       10.80.12.62
    service_description             Current Load
    use                             xiwizard_passive_service
    is_volatile                     1
    max_check_attempts              1
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    xi_timeperiod_24x7
    notification_interval           60
    notification_period             xi_timeperiod_24x7
    contacts                        nagiosadmin
    stalking_options                o,w,u,c
    _xiwizard                       passivecheck
    register                        1
    }

define service {
    host_name                       10.80.12.53,10.80.12.62
    service_description             PING
    use                             xiwizard_passive_service
    check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,80%!!!!!!
    is_volatile                     1
    max_check_attempts              1
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    xi_timeperiod_24x7
    notification_interval           60
    notification_period             xi_timeperiod_24x7
    contacts                        nagiosadmin
    stalking_options                o,w,c,u,
    _xiwizard                       passivecheck
    register                        1
    }
```

I would like to copy the lines containing contact* from the first file to another file updating or adding the contact* lines in another file.

I was trying something like:

grep contac* /usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts/$file_name >/tmp/contacts

sed -i '/define service {/r/tmp/contacts' /usr/local/nagios/etc/services/$file_name}

But with that, I´m just copying the lines from the first file to another.
I need to get this result:

```
 define service {
    contacts                        nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić
    contact_groups                  Testna
    host_name                       10.80.12.62
    service_description             Current Load
    use                             xiwizard_passive_service
    is_volatile                     1
    max_check_attempts              1
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    xi_timeperiod_24x7
    notification_interval           60
    notification_period             xi_timeperiod_24x7
    stalking_options                o,w,u,c
    _xiwizard                       passivecheck
    register                        1
    }

 define service {
    contacts                        nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić
    contact_groups                  Testna
    host_name                       10.80.12.53,10.80.12.62
    service_description             PING
    use                             xiwizard_passive_service
    check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,80%!!!!!!
    is_volatile                     1
    max_check_attempts              1
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    check_period                    xi_timeperiod_24x7
    notification_interval           60
    notification_period             xi_timeperiod_24x7
    stalking_options                o,w,c,u,
    _xiwizard                       passivecheck
    register                        1
    }
```

Comment: Nagios config parsers exist in Python, Perl, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should work, but will de-indent the files. It needs additional spacing for those `echo` calls if you also need to keep the indentation.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

if (( $# != 2 )); then
  echo Usage: nagios-contacts.sh host-file service-file >&2
  exit 1
fi

declare -A CONFIG CONFIGS
while read KEY VALUE; do
  [[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="$VALUE"
done <$1

while read LINE; do
  if [[ $LINE == *"define service {"* ]]; then
    for KEY in ${!CONFIG[*]}; do
      CONFIGS[$KEY]=0
    done
  elif [[ $LINE == *}* ]]; then
    for KEY in ${!CONFIG[*]}; do
      [[ ${CONFIGS[$KEY]} == 1 ]] && unset CONFIGS[$KEY]
    done
    for KEY in ${!CONFIGS[*]}; do
      echo $KEY ${CONFIG[$KEY]}
    done
    unset CONFIGS
    declare -A CONFIGS
  elif [[ $LINE == *contact@(s|_groups)* ]]; then
    read KEY VALUE <<<"$LINE"
    CONFIGS[$KEY]=1
    LINE="$LINE,${CONFIG[$KEY]}"
  fi
  echo "$LINE"
done <$2 | tee $2.new
# maybe:
#   mv $2.new $2
echo Saved output to $2.new
```

It uses two bash arrays, one called CONFIG which will hold the `contacts` and `contact_groups` value from the first file. Then the CONFIGS array will hold the same keys but with values 0 (config not found, needs the whole line) or 1 (config found, value needs to be appended).

The glob matching is not quite as strict, I used `*` instead of just spaces and doesn't handle same line defines, but it does the job for the files you pasted.

Enjoy!

Comment: I didn’t make it to change the file, I created a modified file called the same as the original with the .new extension. The message after you run the script mentions the exact file name. I also added a comment about possibly renaming that file to the original but didn’t meant to make any potentially destructive operations from start.

Comment: You're welcome! It would be nice if you could upvote my response, then.

Comment: I did but I don´t have enough rep for that to be visible. :/

Comment: can I somehow add to the script to skip the xi*values in the contact* lines, for example if in the contact line is value ximgersic, to skip that and append the rest? In the example in the contact line if there is "nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić, ximgersic" that the result would be "nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić", without the xi*. :/

Comment: I'm a bash advocate, but in this situation, a sed can do the magic trick. You can try something along the lines with `sed -e 's/, xi[^,]*//g'`. That will work for what you have above, but you might want to tweak it further for more complex filtering.

Comment: I tried with sed, the exact command sed '/contact*/s/,xi[^ ]*//g' and tried to put it among the several places within the script but none of my tries worked for me. ;/

Answer (score 0):

@Alin Dobre - can I somehow add to the script to skip the xivalues in the contact lines, for example if in the contact line is value ximgersic, to skip that and append the rest? In the example in the contact line if there is "nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić, ximgersic" that the result would be "nagiosadmin,Ivan Ivić,Ivana Ivić", without the xi*  ?

Comment: @Alin Dobre - I tried with sed, the exact command sed '/contact*/s/,xi[^ ]*//g' and tried to put it among the several places within the script but none of my tries worked for me. ;/

Answer (score 0):

In my script above, the line that reads `LINE="$LINE,${CONFIG[$KEY]}"` should be replaced with
`` LINE=`sed -r -e 's/,[ ]?xi[^,]//g' <<<"$LINE,${CONFIG[$KEY]}" `` and then you'll have the xi filtered.